# MOSFET circuit in saturation

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

I need to resolve this problem, but I'm confused with the current through every resistance because I don't know if the current is divided by each resistance or is the same and simply VGS is equal to -1, please help me.  [image]

Comment: You need to show us your work. As a tip, you can use a source transformation and you can simplify the right side to a voltage source (2V) + resistance (1R).

Comment: The current answer is this https://tinyurl.com/23tg3dv7 and the math [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2+%3D+2*x+%2B+V%2C+x+%3D+0.001*%28V+-+1%29%5E2)

Comment: Wow it is a really differente answer comparing mine, but since the original current source was in Ampers, and K is in mA, its makes sense

Answer (score 1):

> *please help me*

**Hint**. Here is how to transform the voltage source to make life easier: -

[image]

Can you see how to combine the two 1 amp current sources and parallel resistor back to a single voltage source in series with 1 Ω resistor.

Then you are left with a single voltage source, two 1 Ω resistors (in series) and the MOSFET. At this point you use the formulas in your picture to find \$I_{DS}\$.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, it really helped me out, I transformed the current source into a voltage source, equal to 2V, then I did kirchhoff voltage law and found VGS, which is equal to 1.5V. With this value I found IDS = 0.25 mA, thank you. I don't now if can you please tell me if I'm right?

Comment: 0.25 A (not mA)

Comment: Oh, it's true thank you

Comment: @Ranjitnapulasem you can use a circuit simulator to check your answer. Please take the [2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to see what you do next if there are no further queries.

Comment: Thank you, but I got a question, at the moment to find vgs, since its a quadratic equation it gives two results, the first one is 0 and the second one is 1.5, which one is the correct? Considering the transistor is in saturation mode

Comment: The sensible one definitely sounds like 1.5 volts @Ranjitnapulasem

Comment: @Ranjitnapulasem I think jp314 is giving you bad information here; I can't see how it is amps of current given that k = 0.0025 amps per volt. Also, with 1.5 volts as Vgs, show how you got 2.5 mA for IDS. It would be half of that for 1.5 volts.

Comment: @jp314 I think you may be giving the OP a bum-steer. Did you think k was 2 amps per volt maybe?

Comment: Andy, could you see this please tinyurl.com/23tg3dv7 and the math link, by @G36

Comment: The link doesn’t work

Comment: Oh, sorry, there's a comment above this and the links work, I think his answer makes sense, since I was wrong with A and mA.

Comment: @Ranjitnapulasem I don't know what to make of it. Your question basically boiled down to this: *I don't know if the current is divided by each resistance or is the same* and, I have shown you how to resolve this through source transformation. I believe I have answered your question. I have tried to help with advice also but, I'm unsure what else I can provide you with. Remember, this is a Q and A site; you asked a question about helping you and, I answered with source transformation hints and, that is as far as I am able to go. I have no idea what you used for k. This answer is done now.